# Astronomically high functions, before returning to zero (reference request anyone?)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I was once on a train a few years back chatting to the adjacent passenger who just so happened to be a Mathematician en route to a conference to celebrate the life of another Mathematician who had discovered a class of functions which soar astronomically high, but then eventually return to zero (and stay near zero I believe). It's a rather vague memory, but I wondered if, with this tit-bit of info, anyone might know the name of these types of function, who was the discoverer, and possibly have any references? For my own work I'm interested in functions which get "extremely" close to zero, but do not vanish, before returning back to "reasonable" values.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem

Comment: @vadim123 wow, thank you :-)

Comment: This was probably the conference https://philevents.org/event/show/8070

Comment: Yes, that will be it - the date is about right :-)